# How to do an average based on two criteria with lookup?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to do an average between 7 days, the problem is that the information I want the function to look for is 4 rows under one another. Maybe it has something to do with the function rows, or counta ?

The second thing is, that in column B I have dates, on which I had a question yesterday and somebody solved it, so thank you.
So now I have one visible date and then 3 same but invisible dates (based on formatting), and I want to look for data in another column (C) which gives me the results from column (D) and makes an average with data from other dates.

So far i was able to come up with this `=AVERAGE(AND(LOOKUP(TODAY();B12:B;D12:D);(LOOKUP("kcal";C12:C;D12:D)));(AND(LOOKUP(TODAY()-1;B12:B;D12:D);(LOOKUP("kcal";C12:C;D12:D)))))` and then it will continue TODAY()-2,-3....-7.

But this gives me "Can't devide by zero" error

Without the invisible dates it would be easy to do, but then I wouldnt be able to sort it. It would look like this `=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(TODAY();B12:B;D12:D);(LOOKUP(TODAY()-1;B12:B;D12:D)))`

Link to my fake spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tW8Wi18Ka12l4DNkRYoZdazu5X2MitKqwp38AGVzoVI

Edit: Only possible solution I came up with now was to put in column A values from column D, but only the first value and 4x, now this formula: `=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(TODAY();B12:B;A12:A);(LOOKUP(TODAY()-1;B12:B;A12:A));(LOOKUP(TODAY()-2;B12:B;A12:A));` ... till -7 works.
Then I can hide with formatting the column A, its not a perfect solution and Im sure there is a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my newly added sheet ("Erik Help"). This formula is in cell D1:

`=AVERAGE(FILTER(D12:D;B12:B>=TODAY()-6;B12:B<=TODAY();C12:C="calories";D12:D<>""))`

I used `FILTER` to filter ***in*** only those values that meet these conditions:

• Has a date between today and six days ago
• Contains the word "calories" in Col C
• Contains a number in Col D

Then `AVERAGE` acts only on those values.

By the way, your own formula was producing the wrong result, because you were including *eight* days, not seven.

You will notice, in my sheet, that there is no longer any need for the Col-A values.

I also replaced your many row-by-row formulas in D11:D with one formula in D11 that produces the header and all results for rows where there are food values. You didn't specifically ask for this; but since I noticed it while I was in there, I gave you that option as well.

Comment: oh wow, that's a very smart way of tackling it ! I guess I would have figured out after 7 days that it is still showing me N/A lol, should have tested that. I did not know that it was possible to do the thing in cell D11 ! Last question that sparked in my head thanks to the clever solution in cell D11, is there a solution to the situation in column B?

Comment: I don't know what "the situation in column B" is. At a glance, it appears you are wanting to sort/re-sort by date in Col B. And if that is the case, you *must* have a date in each cell. If you are asking something different, however, per Stack's intention of keeping things organized for future reference, please post each question separately. I will keep an eye out for it if you do post the new question.

Comment: I posted the question yesterday. I wanted to filter out data with the "Slicer" function - to show me just todays data, because when the list gets longer, for example in 3 months, i would have to do a lot of scrolling. But now that you said I must have date in each cell, then there is no workaround. Anyways, thanks so much for the help.